# Tables extending into the right/outer margin

Tags: tables, margins

I have some wide tables (might be figures, too) that don’t fit into `\textwidth`. If the `draft` document option is active, there’s a black border on the right indicating that it’s wider than allowed.

How can I calculate the maximum width, i.e. the distance from text start at the left to margin paragraph end at the right?

How can I tell LaTeX to respect this maximum width for tables and figures?

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\marginpar{This is a \texttt{marginpar} with multiple lines}
\blindtext

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.16\textwidth}}    % <-- trial-and-error value
\blindtext
\end{tabular}
\caption{A wide table that shall extend into the right margin,
         but no wider than margin notes or margin paragraphs do.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For figures you can use `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{/path/to/image}`. In your example of the table, you have only one column and you specified that it should be 16% larger than `\textwidth`. You should use a number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Is real example a one column table (which seems odd, why tabular at all) In that case you just want `\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep-2\tabcolsep` But if you need to take account of `l` and `c` column natural width, it is harder (`tabularx` package can help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Actual tables have at least 2 columns, of course. The example shows a table that I want not to result in a black bar in `draft` mode, because it doesn‘t extend beyond the margin paragraph width.

Comment: @Crissov yes but there is a big difference (in solution method) between a table where all columns are `p` type (so you know the width in advance) and tables where any column is `c/l/r` (where the column width depends on the data) as in the latter case the desired width of the `p` column to fit your margin space depends on the content of the other columns of the table.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I “just” want to increase the float width at which `draft` starts nagging, to the (value of the) expression you kindly provided. Column styles really shouldn’t matter. It could be a figure instead, after all. If I wanted fixed-width tables, I know I could use `tabularx` or `tabu` with said value. I’m *not* asking for a solution to actually keep my table below that threshold.

Comment: @Crissov oh good that means the answer I posted is the answer you want:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define a `widetable` environment that stretches to the outer margin. (To simplify things I'm assuming `oneside` with the marginpar space on the right). That allows the content, including the caption, to extend into the marginpar space.

Then you can use `@{}` to suppress the column padding and:

[image]

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{widetable}
{\table
 \advance\hsize\marginparwidth
 \advance\hsize\marginparsep
 \@parboxrestore}
{\endtable}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\marginpar{This is a \texttt{marginpar} with multiple lines}
\blindtext

\begin{widetable}
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{\linewidth}@{}}    % <-- trial-and-error value
\blindtext
\end{tabular}
\caption{A wide table that shall extend into the right margin,
         but no wider than margin notes or margin paragraphs do.}
\end{widetable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Tanks. The `\advance\hsize` part seems to be what I was looking for, indeed. Ideally, it would just work for all floats, but `widetable` and `widefigure` environments are fine, too.

Comment: @Crissov if you want to do all floats then `\let\old@float\@float\def\@float{\advance\columnwidth\marginparwidthadvance\columnwidth\marginparsep\old@float}`  probably works

Answer (score 3):

Well, you should never have anything bleeding into the margin like this. However, you can solve the problem by adding a `\hspace*`:

```
\documentclass[draft]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindtext
\marginpar{This is a \texttt{marginpar} with multiple lines}
\blindtext

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{p{1.16\textwidth}}    % <-- trial-and-error value
\blindtext
\end{tabular}\hspace*{-0.5\textwidth}
\caption{A wide table that shall extend into the right margin,
         but no wider than margin notes or margin paragraphs do.}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

The value `0.5\textwidth` should be safe since your margin is probably not larger than half of the text width anyways. However, every time you use this in a final document, Schrödinger kills a kitten (instantly, no waiting and no probability).

Comment: If one (extensively) uses margin notes, which never appear next to floats like tables and figures, I think it’s a viable typographic choice – and not too unusual – to let floats take the same maximum width as paragraphs plus margin notes. However, your code successfully suppresses the black bar, although I don’t know exactly why and I was hoping for something to put in the preamble, like hypothetic `\maxfloatwidth=\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparwidth+\marginparsep-2\tabcolsep` (see David Carlisle’s comment). Also, there are more than enough stray cats.

Comment: @Crissov that it should be done in a systematic way, and there is surely a question about it on the site. You can do `\hsize\maxfloatwidth`. But then you need to determine whether it's a recto or verso page, and on verso, it's much more complicated. Is that what you want? If so, please state it more clearly.

Comment: I searched for it, of course, but unsuccessfully. Luckily, my current use case is single-sided.